# AWS Lambda with API Gateway returning 500 error with hello-world blueprint

Tags: aws-lambda

I am getting {"message": "Internal server error"} on AWS Lambda function.

Here are my steps:

[image]

[image]

Adding API Gateway

[image]

Deploying API
[image]

Api settings:

Authorization None
API Key Not required

> (omitted secret URL)

Results:

> {"message": "Internal server error"}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hello-world` blueprint does not work with an API Gateway trigger. To get a basic call working, change the code of your lambda function to:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: 'Hello, World!'
    };
    return response;
};
```